# Save Join Result to the Same Table

Tags: sql, join, stored-procedures, insert, transformation

I'm trying to create a stored procedure to move and transform the data from STG to INT,
so I wrote this``

```
        CREATE PROCEDURE STGtoINTBudaget

       AS
       BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON
            Truncate table [INT].[fact_budget]
            INSERT INTO [INT].[fact_budget]
            SELECT * FROM [STG].[budget]

            Insert INTO [INT].[fact_budget]
            select b.[Date]
           ,s.StoreId
           ,b.[Sales]
           ,b.[Margin]
              from 
             [INT].[fact_budget] b 
             join int.DIMStores s on s.StoreCode = b.Store

              END
              GO
```

It says that 14,000 affected but the fact_budget table doesn't change, I want to replace the store in budget with store id from stores.
storecode and store are the mutual columns.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE STGtoINTBudaget
   AS
   BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON
        Truncate table [INT].[fact_budget]
        
        Insert INTO [INT].[fact_budget]
        select b.[Date]
       ,s.StoreId
       ,b.[Sales]
       ,b.[Margin]
         FROM [STG].[budget] b
         join int.DIMStores s on s.StoreCode = b.Store

END
GO
```

May be you need something like this? I can no see any reason in the
INSERT INTO [INT].[fact_budget]
SELECT * FROM [STG].[budget]

Comment: because the [int] table is empty unless I move the data from [stg] (source) to it, and it's required to do so with stored procedures.